# Confusion about Java reference

Tags: java, reference

Say I have a simple `Node` class:

```
public class Node {
    public Integer data = null;
    public Node next = null; 

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Now I create a linked list using this nodes:

```
    Node n1 = new Node(1);
    Node n2 = new Node(2);
    Node n3 = new Node(3);
    Node n4 = new Node(4);
    n1.next = n2;
    n2.next = n3;
    n3.next = n4;
```

This is basically: `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null`

So far so good. Now if I am right, n1, n2, n3, and n4 are holding the addresses where the respective instances of   `Node` are stored. So I go ahead, and do this:

```
n2 = n3;
```

i.e. put the address that is stored in n3 also into n2.

So I would expect an output list like this: `1 -> 3 -> 4 -> null` 
But the output I get is still: `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null`.

What am I misunderstanding? How is the list still intact?

Comment: Unless you are changing `next`, you can fiddle with n2 and n3's reference all you want and that won't change what the nodes themselves are pointing to.

Comment: Oh I see. So when I say `n1.next = n2`, n1.next will keep pointing to the original n2 object where ever it is in the memory. Basically assignment happened by "value of reference".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way a linked list works, you only need an intact reference to the first node in order to traverse the list.

All the line `n2 = n3` is doing is changing the reference in n2 from node 2 to node 3, the node itself is unchanged.

`n1.next()` will still equal the 2nd node.

`n1.next().next()` will equal the  3rd node.

`n1.next().next().next` will equal the 4th node.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically changing what n2 is referring to not n2.next. n2 and n2.next are references pointing to 2 different objects. You will have to set n1.next to n3 for the behavior you are expecting. But again n2.next will still be pointing to n3.